# How to start a program when another one is started

Tags: windows-7, windows

I want a program to start each time another one is starting.

Here's an example: Each time I start Google Chrome, I would like iTunes to start at the same time.

Also, I want it to start when I click a link in my browser that starts a program (like "view in iTunes on the iTune website).

I do not want to have to do with a .bat file.

I am running on Windows 7

Comment: Can you clarify.  The first option is that if you open Chrome, itunes starts too.  But the second option - when you click a link that opens itunes, you want something else to open as well?

Comment: Those are just examples, basically I want to start mutiple programs when I want to start one or another program wants to start it

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could probably set up specific pairs of apps to run using the registry, and altering what deals with mimetypes.  However another more generic way, and far more complex, is to use the Task Scheduler.  The task scheduler can start an app based various types of triggers, including Event Log entries.

So all we need is to ensure an event is created whenever an application starts, and then create a scheduled task to start whenever the event is logged.

## Enable 'application start' logging

1. Start and enter `secpol.msc` into the Run box
2. Navigate to *Local Policies/Audit Policy*
3. Double Click *Audit process tracking* and enable `Success`

Now, if you start any application, if you look in Event Viewer / Security Log you will see a *Process Creation* event `4688` each time an application is started.

## Create scheduled task based on trigger

1. Open *Task Scheduler* and create a new task
2. On the *General* Tab, give the task a name
3. On the *Triggers* tab, create a new trigger, and choose *On an event* as the trigger
4. Choose *Custom*, and click *Edit Event Filter*
5. Change the *Filter* settings as follows:

[image: Task filter]

Now Switch to the *XML* tab, and enable *edit query manually*

You will see the following

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
      *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and Task = 13312 and (band(Keywords,9007199254740992)) and (EventID=4688)]] 
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Now you just need to add the application you want to cause the trigger. For example, this one uses `notepad.exe` as the trigger:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
     *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and Task = 13312 and (band(Keywords,9007199254740992)) and (EventID=4688)]] 
   and 
     *[EventData[Data[@Name='NewProcessName'] and (Data='C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe')]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Click `Ok` for this, then `Ok` to close the trigger dialog box.

Now choose the *Action* tab, and create a new action, that is `Start a Program`, and browse to the app you want to start along with the trigger application.

Comment: I dont have anything named secpol.msc. I made a small reserach and I think its because it is not available in Windows 7 Home Premium. Is there another way?

Comment: The audit policy needs to be changed for this to work, and it is absent from W7HP.  There are a few guides out there for installing gpedit.msc on W7HP which you might want to try.  You can edit the audit policy with this too, in `Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Audit Policy`

Comment: @TheBird956 Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: I do not have the correct windows version. I think I need Pro to do that, but I tried on my brother's computer who has Pro installed and it works.

Comment: To set the trigger to program/process exit/termination/close instead of start/create, this XML for the event filter worked for me:

`<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
      *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (band(Keywords,9007199254740992)) and (EventID=4689)]] 
      and
      *[EventData[(Data='PATH TO THE DESIRED EXE')]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>`

Comment: I always get `An event filter for a trigger is not valid` error when pressing OK at the end of the task creation. However the event filter looks exactly like yours (I generated it myself) with the exception that my program sits in the Program Files (x86) folder.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I was using Sysmon before but it's way more involved. You can skip all of step five and just go to the manual route: *Now Switch to the XML tab, and enable edit query manually* and then use the code you've pasted as an example.

Comment: On Windows 10, @Name='NewProcessName' needs to be changed to @Name='ProcessName'

Comment: It is possible to activate GPEDIT.msc on Win10 Home (see https://www.giga.de/downloads/microsoft-windows/tipps/gpedit.msc-fehlt-einfach-nachinstallieren-windows-10-home/). They use a BAT file, as Admin, worked for me:

`pushd "%~dp0"`

'dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientExtensions-Package~3*.mum >List.txt`

`dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientTools-Package~3*.mum >>List.txt`

`for /f %%i in ('findstr /i . List.txt 2^>nul') do dism /online /norestart /add-package:"%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\%%i"`

Comment: @Paul your answer basically works for me, but when I run the notepad.exe multiple times, the scheduled task is only triggered once. How can I trigger the task whenever I run notepad.exe ?

Comment: @Paul could you please provide an example of what you mean by "browse to the app you want to start along with the trigger application"? I've got the path to a batch file I want to run (assumption: "the app you want to start") when Excel starts (assumption: "the trigger application"). No action appears to occur upon Excel start. Do I need a second piece of information, i.e. something to do with the path to Excel? (Of course I could have structured the XML incorrectly and the event isn't being caught.) Thanks for such a well-documented idea!

Comment: Not deleting my comment above in case anyone else has the same question. (And it's past the edit cutoff.) All that's needed is the path to the batch file. As it turns out, my actual issue (Windows 10 syntax) was addressed by @RobG *and* I misinterpreted leaving _Audit Process Tracking_ enabled - I thought it was just to get the event ID. Its role is to create the log entry event that Task Scheduler looks for. Duh... This is genius @Paul!

Comment: I love how you start with an alleged "easy way" and then you dismiss it and proceed with the "far more complex" one.

Comment: Are there any downsides to tracking all process' success events?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that [Paul's answer](https://superuser.com/a/745336/327009) above might work for most of people, however for some reason I could not get it to work with my program.

When specifying the path for Notepad.exe, the Task was created successfully; when I changed the path to the one of the program I was intending to use, I always got `An event filter for a trigger is not valid` error when pressing OK at the end of the task creation. Consider that the event filter looks exactly like Paul's (I generated it myself following his procedure) with the exception that my program sitted in the Program Files (x86) folder.

I eventually solved my problem by installing an external software, [Bill's Process Manager](https://www.bill2-software.com/processmanager/download-en.shtml).
Kudos to [this StackExchange answer](https://superuser.com/a/1115833/327009) for it.

Comment: Same error message here. "An event filter for a trigger is not valid". My program was in a folder outside Programs and outside Windows. Probably the problem is not in the path.