# Run command / script when program starts in Windows

Tags: windows-10, task-scheduler, lock-screen

I will strive to explain what I want.
I have Windows 10 Pro. I want to create a task in Task Scheduler that causes Windows to lock when someone launches a certain app (in my case - uTorrent).

I’ve created a .bat file containing the following command:

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
```

As I understand, I must put it here. Look at the picture. Am I right?

[image]

But what should I do in the "Triggers" section? 
I guess I should choose “On an event”?

[image]

Note: I could not find “event id” of uTorrent in “event viewer,”  if that matters.

Comment: Why don't you just block the application from running?  Are you not locking the computer for security?

Comment: Do you need it to lock right away? Because you could simply have it run every 2 minutes and modify your script to execute only if the utorrent process is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with [Bill2's Process Manager](http://www.bill2-software.com/processmanager/download-en.shtml).
It gives you the ability to create a rule when a process starts.
The process manager is already configured to start with windows.
You will want to go into options and change the software to English, then check
[image: Checkbox]
`Minimize to system tray instead of exiting when close button is clicked`
to keep the it running in the background.
You can also set a username and password for the interface under the Security menu in options.

**Create a rule to lock windows when uTorrent starts**

1. Open uTorrent
2. Open Bill2's Process Manager
3. Find the uTorrent process and right click on it, select `Create a rule for this process`
4. Click on the `Special Actions` tab
5. [image: Checkbox]`Launch one or many programs`
6. Fire in your lock command `rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation`
7. Hit `Ok` and test your work

Comment: It works!!! It works!!! It works!!! Thank you.

Comment: Awsome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Though not specifically for Windows 10, this answer should work: [How to start a program when another one is started](https://superuser.com/questions/745318/how-to-start-a-program-when-another-one-is-started). The only difference is that you will have to specify a script, not a program.

My intention was to comment this instead of answering but I lack reputation score.