# Enable "audit process tracking" using batch file

Tags: windows, batch, automation, security-policy

I'm following [this post](https://superuser.com/a/745336/725729) and trying to enable **Audit process tracking**.

> Local Security Policy > Local Policies > Audit Policy > Double Click **Audit process tracking** and *enable*.

I'm hoping for a quicker way to do it (preferably a batch file).

I took a look at [`ntrights`](https://ss64.com/nt/ntrights.html) but can't seem to figure out *how* to enable it .

---

I just need the batch file to enable "Success" audits.

Comment: This might help: https://serverfault.com/questions/133104/how-can-i-edit-local-security-policy-from-a-batch-file  Or this: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2016/01/21/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/

Comment: @DougDeden I saw the SF post, that's how I found out about `ntrights`, still confused though. I will check out the other page you linked, thanks.

Comment: It seems like this should do it: `auditpol /set /subcategory:"Process Creation" /success:enable`. But I don't see that doing that correlates with the desired line in Local Security Policy, at least I my testing. Maybe it will spur someone else to contribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked for so long too. I figured out the answer!

To check the current state :

```
auditpol /get /subcategory:"Process Creation"
```

This next line will make the change. It will set the process creation to Enabled.

```
auditpol /set /subcategory:"Process Creation"
```

Check the state again and you'll see the change.

Alternatively, you could change all of the "detail tracking" policies, as "process creation" is a subcategory of "detail tracking".
Like this:

```
auditpol /set /category:"Detailed Tracking"
```

Thanks to Doug Deden for hiting me on the auditpol command.