# Task Scheduler trigger task when a Process Terminates

Tags: windows, process, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to use Windows 10 Task Scheduler to create a task that is triggered when a particular process is terminated.

My first step was enabling `Audit process tracking` in the Group Policy Editor (`Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Audit Policy`). This turns on event logging for whenever a processes start or stop. The termination (stop) event ID in Windows is `4689` ([link](https://kb.eventtracker.com/evtpass/evtPages/EventId_4689_Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing_61051.asp)). I can now see (in the Event Log) when processes are terminated, including the specific process I'm wanting to trigger an task on.

Next I attempted to create a task in Task Scheduler that will execute when this particular process is terminated. The particular application process name I want to watch for is `C:\Program Files\path\to\my\application.exe`.

I created a custom event filter for it and used the following XML:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
      *[System[(EventID="4689")]] and *[EventData[Data[@Name="ProcessName"]="C:\Program Files\path\to\my\application.exe"]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

This doesn't seem to want to work though. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong on the syntax. I don't get any errors or anything. My task simply doesn't get triggered.

Comment: one thing you could try is using Microsoft-Windows-ProcessExitMonitor source.  It would be interesting to know if it triggers.  E.g. 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\processtomonitor.exe]
"GlobalFlag"=dword:00000200

Answer (score 2):

I'm wrestling with the very same thing, it's maddening. The Event Filter triggers on Process Creation (Task = 13312, EventID=4688) but NOT on Termination...

Set up same as OP, I also see the Creation and Termination events in Event Viewer, made a task to trigger a .bat on Process Termination (Task = 13313, EventID=4689) but the event does not trigger it. When I run the task manually it of course works. The filter goes like this:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
     *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and Task = 13313 and (band(Keywords,9007199254740992)) and (EventID=4689)]]
   and 
     *[EventData[Data[@Name='NewProcessName'] and (Data='C:\Program Files\AppName.exe')]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

What th am I missing here???

EDIT: Aha! I was missing [this](https://superuser.com/questions/745318/how-to-start-a-program-when-another-one-is-started#comment1857877_745336). Now it triggers on Terminate.

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
     *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (band(Keywords,9007199254740992)) and (EventID=4689)]]
   and 
     *[EventData[(Data='C:\Program Files\AppName.exe')]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Comment: The filter works the same both ways, doesn't care for `Task` nor `ProcessName`

Comment: What is `band(Keywords,9007199254740992)`?