# How to run scheduled task only if none of a group of programs are running?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I have been using Task Scheduler to launch and terminate compiled AutoHotKey scripts depending on whether other apps are launched or terminated. I used information on custom event filters from [this post](https://superuser.com/a/745336) to **launch** the AHK scripts when Adobe apps are launched, and I have used information from [this post](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/193951-task-scheduler-how-end-program-when-another-one-ends.html#post2418338) to **terminate** the AHK scripts when the Adobe apps are terminated.

In this case, I want Task Scheduler to run "TaskbarToggle.exe", only if none of the following apps are running: Photoshop, Illustrator, Audition, Premiere Pro, InDesign, InCopy.

Is it possible to create a custom event filter that can do this, or am I better off finding another way to do this?